# Extract Multiple Words in a Phrase

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula to extract a specific word that starts with a given characters “CCLVL”. It is working fine, however, I also need the formula to extract words that start with “GCFAC” or “CLINK”

How can I make it find these other words – there should never be more than one instance of the word in the text I am extracting from.

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("CCLVL",A2),LEN(A2))," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

Does the description contain `CCLVL123456`?  If so, this is 3rd Party   `CCLVL123456`
Does the description contain `GCFAC4567`  If so, this is 3rd Party
Does the description contain `CLINK95182`  If so, this is 3rd Party

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea here is to cut up a string into an array of words using `FILTERXML` and some xpath to return only those words from that array that interest us. Luckily there is a function called `starts-with()` we can use in an or structure:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., 'CCLVL') or starts-with(., 'GCFAC') or starts-with(., 'CLINK')]")
```

In Excel365 this would return an vertical array, so you may want to use `TRANSPOSE()` or `TEXTJOIN()` in conjunction. Also, if you don't have Excel365, you can use `INDEX()` to retrieve elements from the array in order.

---

In the below example I used:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"?","")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., 'CCLVL') or starts-with(., 'GCFAC') or starts-with(., 'CLINK')]"))
```

[image]

---

For a better understanding of the above, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) post.

Comment: Your explanation of each line is really excellent. We are who still learning excel must read your answers top to bottom line by line.

Comment: Formula is AWESOME just what I needed!!  Thank you ever so much.

Comment: Can this formula be combined with another formula to do the following:  Look in Cell C2 and if cell begins with ABC or DEF put the contents of the cell, else perform formula above.  If the Cell A2 or Cell C2 contain neither of those things then leave blank.  (note cell B2 contains the formula)

Comment: FIGURED IT OUT!!  Here is the formula that I ended up with  ------       =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("abc",A7)),A7,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DEF",A7)),A7,IFERROR(@FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B7," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., 'CCLVL') or starts-with(., 'GCFAC') or starts-with(., 'CLINK') or starts-with(., 'CCQWC') or starts-with(., 'CCQWA')]"),"")))